# Navbar fixed top with jQuery canceling css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress site and managed to put my navbar fixed to the top when I scroll down the page using this code:

```
(function( $ ){   
    var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top; 
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
        }else {        
            jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        }     
   });     
})(jQuery);
```

But now when I click on the icons that I have on the page (on the Products and Services sections), neither the popups nor the the animation applied on the icons work.

When I deactivate this particular jQuery code, the popups work fine.

Is there another way that I can make the navbar fixed to top and still have my icons working fine?

Is there anything wrong on the jQuery?
http://scentology.burnnotice.co.za/

Comment: May i know which icons ?

Comment: @Jacob Goh.The big icons on the products&services section

Comment: Did you check if your navbar has the correct `z-index`? Maybe there are items with higher z-index and your click event is not being applied/propagated properly?

Comment: @Marcus.I just canceled  any z-index on the navbar and nothing different happens. And If you notice,once the navbar is fixed to the top,you will not be able to inspect each element on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appears that your nav is covering the whole screen when it's fixed

screenshot: [image]

it happens because you have a `bottom: 0` css properties on the nav

```
nav#site-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

the solution is to make sure that `bottom: 0` is disabled when it's in fix mode. You can add `bottom: auto !important;` to your .fixed class

```
.fixed {
    top: 4%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: .I definitely need to vote  on your answer. My I ask another question with regards to the navbar or shall we perhaps take this to chat?

Comment: i think you can comment here ?

Comment: Great. If you refresh the page, you will see that when you click on each menu item,it goes to its respective section.Fine.But if you notice, the navbar covers some of the content of the section...in this case the title.
I previously added a margin to each section like this [name="about-us"] {
    height: 55px !important;
    display: block !important;
}.
But it is not really a good practice  at all  because it's very easy to notate that big gap that it creates.
How can I get  my  way around that?

Comment: sorry a bit busy at the moment. will help to advise again later if no one has answered to this yet

Comment: @WosleyAlarico.There is absolutely no problem there.You are just confused because the navbar of your wordpress is taking the place of your site navigation.On your .fixed class replace your top:4% To 0%

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Yes, a fixed height will create a big gap, so it's not an ideal solution. I normal set position the the section's anchor like this, `a[name="products-and-services"] {
    position: relative;
    top: -52px;
}`, try it and you will see how it works !

Comment: I added set  the .fixed class to top:0, added padding top and bottom to the container of each section and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.
Now I want each menu item to get highlighted as I scroll down according to  their respective sections.Think it's called scrollspy. If you can give me a better guide on where to  find the perfect solution  for I'll surely appreciate that.